# Issue with fill() method

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function Show(output, startX, startY){
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
        context.arc(startX, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.fill();
        context.arc(startX + 50, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.stroke();
}
Show(outputcpu, 50, 50);
Show(outputio, 70, 50);
```

I have expect some thing like: `o-o o-o`.

But not sure why I get: `o-o-o-o`.

How to remove the center stroke? (I want to remove the second line o-o**-**o-o)

Comment: The first is `o-o` and the second is placed a little to the right so you have `o1-o2-o1-o2`. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: what I want is: `o1-o2 o3-o4`. But what I get is `o1-o2-o3-o4`. There was a line between o2 and o3 that I want to remove!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**beginPath**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Using_Paths) will seperate your calls: http://jsfiddle.net/CmuT7/1

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d");

function Show(output, startX, startY) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(startX, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.arc(startX + 50, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.stroke();

}
Show('', 50, 50);
Show('', 70, 70);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `moveTo()` or `beginPath()` function to avoind line between those arcs.

```
function Show(output, startX, startY){
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
        context.arc(startX, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.fill();
        context.moveTo(startX +50, startY);
        context.arc(startX + 50, startY, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.stroke();
}
Show(outputcpu, 50, 50);
Show(outputio, 70, 50);
```